# Debugging .NET application from TFS source server like a project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have setup a source and symbol servers together with TFS. I checked in the files, created a build, it built, symbols are there, all fine.

However, when it comes to the debugging, if an exception occurs, it indeed loads the proper source file and stops at the proper line of code but I have no GUI option to view other files from the same check-in. I know that TFS doesn't know how my project is organized etc but the debugging symbols have information about all source files that were used to build this solution.

Is there any way I will be able to setup a breakpoint on some other file than the one where the exception occurred? Also, I would like to be able to go to definition (or peek) at some methods which are not defined in the source file that opened together with the exception.